# Why angular x ngStyle does not update dynamically?

Tags: angular, dynamic, ng-style

I don't understand why this few lines not working.

HTML template:

```
<input class="picked-clear main-line-item main-line-box" type="button" value="" #pickedClear [ngStyle]="style" (click)="handleClearPickedBox($event)" />
```

component.ts:
...

```
export class DatePickerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  placeholder:string = "Select a date";
  style:any = {
    'background-image': "none"
  }

  @ViewChild('pickedBox') pickedBox;
  @ViewChild('pickedClear') pickedClear;

  constructor() { }
  ...


someFunc(){
  ...
  this.style['background-image']="url(assets/img/datePicker/clear.svg)";
  ...
}
...
```

The problem is the following: At the start the button gets the style attribute with the background-image: none value. This is fine but when my script calls the someFunc() the style value is changing but not in the DOM only in the ts.

Thx for your time in advance. :)

---

requested details (rewrited)

date-picker.component.ts:

```
<div class="date-picker">
  <div class="main-line">
    <input class="picked-box main-line-item" type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" value="" #pickedBox (focus)="handlePlaceholderFocus($event)" (blur)="handlePlaceholderBlur($event)" (keyup)="handlePickedBoxChange($event)" />
    <input class="picked-clear main-line-item main-line-box" type="button" value="" #pickedClear [ngStyle]="style" (click)="handleClearPickedBox($event)" />
    <input class="picker-toggle-btn main-line-item main-line-box" type="button" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="picker-cont">

  </div>
</div>
```

date-picker.component.ts:

```
export class DatePickerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  placeholder:string = "Select a date";
  style:any;

  @ViewChild('pickedBox') pickedBox;
  @ViewChild('pickedClear') pickedClear;

  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.style={};
    this.style['background-image']='none';
    this.style['cursor']='auto';
  }
...
handlePickedBoxChange(event){
    var target =          event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    if(target.value.length>0){
      //this.pickedClear.nativeElement.style.backgroundImage = "url(assets/img/datePicker/clear.svg)";
      //this.pickedClear.nativeElement.style.cursor = "pointer";
      if(this.style['cursor']!='pointer'){
        this.style['background-image']=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('url(assets/img/datePicker/clear.svg)');
        this.style['cursor']='pointer';
      }
    }else{
      //this.pickedClear.nativeElement.style.backgroundImage = "none";
      //this.pickedClear.nativeElement.style.cursor = "auto";
      this.style['background-image']='none';
      this.style['cursor']='auto';
    }
  }
...
```

[recent workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u67sC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It should work

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fp6bao)

With the sanitizer, only this way seems to work:

```
<div [style.background-image]="backgroundImageSanitized">
```

Comment: Sadly it did not work :( The DOM still keep the attribute like style="background-image: none"; even after someFunc() called;

Comment: Can you please provide more details about "my script" that calls `someFunc`? Where is it called from. Can you please try to add a button to the component like `<button (click)="someFunc()">click me</button>` and check if the style is updated?

Comment: I updated the question with more informations. Presently the  handlePickedBoxChange(event) fnc fires every time on key pressed in pickedBox.

Comment: Have you tried with a button directly in the component as suggested above?

Comment: As far as I know you don't need `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle` for simple values like `cursor` or int and string values, but you need it for urls.

Comment: I updated the script after your advices and changed the workflow picture

Comment: I still didn't get any feedback if the behavior changes if you add a plain button with a click handler and call the method from there ;-)

Comment: I have tried with the button itself. I used the handleClearPickedBox(event) fnc for it but it had the same workflow.

Comment: Do you get a warning like "WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
" in the browser console?

Comment: I did not get anything like that :(

Comment: "Try it like shown in stackoverflow.com/a/43070098/217408" I tried this way as well but same issue :| still not changing the background-image or the cursor

Comment: Does it work if you add it as inline style or if you add it to `@NgComponent({..., styles: [...]})`?

Comment: I could do like I commented in the handlePickedBoxChange(event) fnc with native javascript DOM manipulating but then I lose the purpose of useing angular.

Comment: First you should figure out why the background style isn't working. For this I suggested to try other approaches any other works. Then we can try to figure out what the root cause is and how to fix that for your preferred way. A reproduction in http://stackblitz.com would be helpful.

Comment: if I write inline like     <input class="picked-clear main-line-item main-line-box" type="button" value="" #pickedClear style="background-image:url(assets/img/datePicker/clear.svg); cursor: pointer;" (click)="handleClearPickedBox($event)" />
works and draws the clear icon,

Comment: Ok. Good to know. Can you please try to reproduce in stackblitz?

Comment: I guess I will try to make the reproduction :)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxti6v
this is something like that the workflow should match the design is disgusting but shows fine the main thing I guess

Comment: A reproduction should be minimal, not maximal ;-)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fp6bao It works either way, but not the one I posted in my answer ;-/